# Get XML value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

XML looks like this

```
   <search>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>John</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Carl</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>John</name>
        </person>
    </persons>
</search>
```

I need to get applicant's details through person Id.

How do I get this using **XSLT**?

Comment: You can use `xsl:key` to achieve this. Have a read up on it at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html for example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to found the answer.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="preg" match="person" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','1')">
    Id: <xsl:value-of select="id"/><br />
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```